SATA link down for PROBOX after upgrade to 23.10
My 8 bay Probox enclosure contains a raid array of several disks and worked just fine before upgrade to 23.10 server edition.
After the upgrade, BIOS detects the drives just fine, but during initialization the device is skipped after many attempts to reset the link.
There are 7 disks in the bays, but I see ata6.15?
None of the disks are present under lspci.
Attaching my dmesg and grub config. I am suspecting that the new kernel has some problem with the driver support of the enclosure.
Any help is appreciated.
Dmesg:
[    5.525810] ata6: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m512@0xfe6ffc00 port 0xfe6ffd80 irq 28
[    5.597736] ACPI: bus type drm_connector registered
[    5.605429] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    5.667211] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    5.704548] md/raid1:md126: active with 2 out of 2 mirrors
[    5.738993] md/raid1:md125: active with 2 out of 2 mirrors
[    5.739340] tg3 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: renamed from eth0
[    5.741160] md126: detected capacity change from 0 to 52393984
[    5.743304]  md126: p1
[    5.772744] md125: detected capacity change from 0 to 4188160
[    5.909789]  md125: p1
[    5.912956] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[   11.493097] ata6: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   16.025097] ata6: softreset failed (device not ready)
[   21.573096] ata6: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   26.105095] ata6: softreset failed (device not ready)
[   31.653094] ata6: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   41.525108] ata6: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[   41.558037] ata6.15: Port Multiplier 1.2, 0x197b:0x321f r0, 8 ports, feat 0x5/0xf
[   41.624862] ata6.00: hard resetting link
[   42.073140] ata6.00: link resume succeeded after 1 retries
[   42.373594] ata6.00: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[   42.405493] ata6.01: hard resetting link
[   42.913591] ata6.01: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[   42.944636] ata6.02: hard resetting link
[   43.449589] ata6.02: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[   43.480084] ata6.03: hard resetting link
[   43.985596] ata6.03: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[   44.015363] ata6.04: hard resetting link
[   45.085130] ata6.04: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
[   45.114653] ata6.04: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 0)
[   45.143557] ata6.05: hard resetting link
[   45.649591] ata6.05: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[   45.678473] ata6.06: hard resetting link
[   46.181591] ata6.06: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[   46.211338] ata6.07: hard resetting link
[   46.717597] ata6.07: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[   46.748358] ata6.00: ATA-8: ST3500418AS, CC46, max UDMA/133
[   46.777922] ata6.00: 976773168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32)
[   46.809016] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   46.839734] ata6.01: ATA-8: ST500DM002-1BD142, KC45, max UDMA/133
[   46.869350] ata6.01: 976773168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32)
[   46.900519] ata6.01: configured for UDMA/133
[   46.930570] ata6.02: ATA-8: ST3500413AS, HP64, max UDMA/100
[   46.959706] ata6.02: 976773168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32)
[   46.990142] ata6.02: configured for UDMA/100
[   47.019788] ata6.03: ATA-8: ST3500413AS, HP64, max UDMA/100
[   47.048428] ata6.03: 976773168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32)
[   47.078040] ata6.03: configured for UDMA/100
[   47.107336] ata6.05: ATA-8: ST3500413AS, JC4B, max UDMA/133
[   47.135895] ata6.05: 976773168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32)
[   47.166040] ata6.05: configured for UDMA/133
[   47.196264] ata6.06: ATA-8: ST32000644NS, SN12, max UDMA/133
[   47.224749] ata6.06: 3907029168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32)
[   62.269085] ata6.06: qc timeout after 15000 msecs (cmd 0xef)
[   62.297756] ata6.06: failed to set xfermode (err_mask=0x5)
[   62.326278] ata6.15: hard resetting link
[   67.869085] ata6.15: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   72.337083] ata6.15: softreset failed (device not ready)
[   72.365918] ata6.15: hard resetting link
[   77.909083] ata6.15: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   82.377085] ata6.15: softreset failed (device not ready)
[   82.406312] ata6.15: hard resetting link
[   87.949083] ata6.15: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   97.817093] ata6.15: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[   97.846809] ata6.00: hard resetting link
[   98.293127] ata6.00: link resume succeeded after 1 retries
[   98.589590] ata6.00: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[   98.618768] ata6.01: hard resetting link
[   99.121598] ata6.01: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[   99.150865] ata6.02: hard resetting link
[   99.653586] ata6.02: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[   99.682791] ata6.03: hard resetting link
[  100.185593] ata6.03: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[  100.214928] ata6.04: hard resetting link
[  101.285126] ata6.04: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
[  101.314630] ata6.04: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 0)
[  101.343480] ata6.05: hard resetting link
[  101.849599] ata6.05: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[  101.878522] ata6.06: hard resetting link
[  102.381595] ata6.06: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[  102.410459] ata6.07: hard resetting link
[  102.913594] ata6.07: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[  102.948914] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  102.980045] ata6.01: configured for UDMA/133
[  103.009826] ata6.02: configured for UDMA/100
[  103.038964] ata6.03: configured for UDMA/100
[  103.067601] ata6.05: configured for UDMA/133
[  118.333093] ata6.06: qc timeout after 15000 msecs (cmd 0xef)
[  118.358694] ata6.06: failed to set xfermode (err_mask=0x5)
[  118.384005] ata6.15: hard resetting link
[  123.925081] ata6.15: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[  128.393083] ata6.15: softreset failed (device not ready)
[  128.418821] ata6.15: hard resetting link
[  133.961083] ata6.15: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[  138.425081] ata6.15: softreset failed (device not ready)
[  138.450989] ata6.15: hard resetting link
[  143.993082] ata6.15: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[  153.857092] ata6.15: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[  153.883434] ata6.00: hard resetting link
[  154.325124] ata6.00: link resume succeeded after 1 retries
[  154.617588] ata6.00: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[  154.643507] ata6.01: hard resetting link
[  155.145596] ata6.01: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[  155.171704] ata6.02: hard resetting link
[  155.673583] ata6.02: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[  155.700045] ata6.03: hard resetting link
[  156.201590] ata6.03: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[  156.228111] ata6.04: hard resetting link
[  157.293123] ata6.04: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
[  157.319658] ata6.04: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 0)
[  157.345614] ata6.05: hard resetting link
[  157.845588] ata6.05: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[  157.872244] ata6.06: hard resetting link
[  158.373594] ata6.06: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[  158.401804] ata6.07: hard resetting link
[  158.905593] ata6.07: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[  158.937074] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  158.968616] ata6.01: configured for UDMA/133
[  158.998825] ata6.02: configured for UDMA/100
[  159.028117] ata6.03: configured for UDMA/100
[  159.056607] ata6.05: configured for UDMA/133
[  174.141082] ata6.06: qc timeout after 15000 msecs (cmd 0xef)
[  174.166469] ata6.06: failed to set xfermode (err_mask=0x5)
[  174.191566] ata6.06: failed to recover link after 3 tries, disabling
[  174.216566] ata6.06: disable device
[  174.241064] ata6.15: hard resetting link
[  179.781080] ata6.15: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[  184.245080] ata6.15: softreset failed (device not ready)
[  184.269468] ata6.15: hard resetting link
[  185.897816] md/raid1:md127: active with 2 out of 2 mirrors
[  185.922226] md127: detected capacity change from 0 to 1021952
[  185.951459]  md127: p1
[  189.813102] ata6.15: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[  194.277090] ata6.15: softreset failed (device not ready)
[  194.301772] ata6.15: hard resetting link
[  199.841090] ata6.15: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[  209.705102] ata6.15: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[  210.044850] ata6.06: failed to read SCR 0 (Emask=0x40)
[  210.069848] ata6.06: failed to write SCR 1 (Emask=0x40)
[  210.094593] ata6.06: failed to clear SError.N (errno=-5)
[  210.119185] ata6.15: hard resetting link
[  215.657088] ata6.15: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[  220.121089] ata6.15: softreset failed (device not ready)
[  220.145769] ata6.15: hard resetting link
[  225.685088] ata6.15: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[  230.149088] ata6.15: softreset failed (device not ready)
[  230.173671] ata6.15: hard resetting link
[  235.713089] ata6.15: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)

[  245.577093] ata6.15: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[  249.288822] ata6.06: failed to read SCR 0 (Emask=0x40)
[  249.312701] ata6.06: failed to write SCR 1 (Emask=0x40)
[  249.336528] ata6.06: failed to clear SError.N (errno=-5)
[  249.360393] ata6.15: hard resetting link
[  254.901077] ata6.15: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[  259.365077] ata6.15: softreset failed (device not ready)
[  259.390020] ata6.15: hard resetting link
[  264.929077] ata6.15: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[  269.393077] ata6.15: softreset failed (device not ready)
[  269.419130] ata6.15: hard resetting link
[  274.961077] ata6.15: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[  284.825088] ata6.15: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[  285.168585] ata6.06: failed to read SCR 0 (Emask=0x40)
[  285.196340] ata6.06: failed to write SCR 1 (Emask=0x40)
[  285.223994] ata6.06: failed to clear SError.N (errno=-5)
[  285.251781] ata6.15: hard resetting link
[  290.793076] ata6.15: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[  295.261077] ata6.15: softreset failed (device not ready)
[  295.289720] ata6.15: hard resetting link
[  300.833076] ata6.15: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[  305.301076] ata6.15: softreset failed (device not ready)
[  305.329217] ata6.15: hard resetting link
[  310.873075] ata6.15: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[  320.741088] ata6.15: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[  321.084576] ata6.06: failed to read SCR 0 (Emask=0x40)
[  321.112818] ata6.06: failed to write SCR 1 (Emask=0x40)
[  321.140940] ata6.06: failed to clear SError.N (errno=-5)
[  321.168431] ata6: failed to recover PMP after 5 tries, giving up
[  321.195937] ata6.15: Port Multiplier detaching
[  321.222861] ata6.00: Entering standby power mode
[  321.249570] ata6.00: STANDBY IMMEDIATE failed (err_mask=0x40)
[  321.276805] ata6.00: disable device
[  321.303801] ata6.01: Entering standby power mode
[  321.330849] ata6.01: STANDBY IMMEDIATE failed (err_mask=0x40)
[  321.357925] ata6.01: disable device
[  321.384309] ata6.02: Entering standby power mode
[  321.410827] ata6.02: STANDBY IMMEDIATE failed (err_mask=0x40)
[  321.437422] ata6.02: disable device
[  321.463304] ata6.03: Entering standby power mode
[  321.489277] ata6.03: STANDBY IMMEDIATE failed (err_mask=0x40)
[  321.515299] ata6.03: disable device
[  321.540606] ata6.05: Entering standby power mode
[  321.565733] ata6.05: STANDBY IMMEDIATE failed (err_mask=0x40)
[  321.591410] ata6.05: disable device
[  321.616835] ata6.00: disable device
[  327.157076] ata6: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[  331.681075] ata6: softreset failed (device not ready)
[  337.221074] ata6: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[  341.745074] ata6: softreset failed (device not ready)
[  347.285074] ata6: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[  357.149086] ata6: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[  357.175032] ata6: EH complete

And here is the grub config:
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomdmonddf nomdmonisw ipv6.disable=1 consoleblank=300 apparmor=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=off"
# If your computer has multiple operating systems installed, then you
# probably want to run os-prober. However, if your computer is a host
# for guest OSes installed via LVM or raw disk devices, running
# os-prober can cause damage to those guest OSes as it mounts
# filesystems to look for things.
#GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

And lspci for fun:
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation E7230/3000/3010 Memory Controller Hub
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation E7230/3000/3010 PCI Express Root Port
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GR/GH/GHM (ICH7 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 01)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GR/GH/GHM (ICH7 Family) PCI Express Port 6 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 01)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6702PXH PCI Express-to-PCI Bridge A (rev 09)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5721 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 11)
05:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)
06:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] ES1000 (rev 02)

And lsblk while we are at it, without any of the 7 disks in the day that BIOS listed:
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0           7:0    0     4K  1 loop  /snap/bare/5
loop1           7:1    0   104M  1 loop  /snap/core/16928
loop2           7:2    0  55.7M  1 loop  /snap/core18/2823
loop3           7:3    0    64M  1 loop  /snap/core20/2318
loop4           7:4    0  74.2M  1 loop  /snap/core22/1380
loop5           7:5    0 140.7M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/111
loop6           7:6    0   1.6M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-system-monitor/186
sda             8:0    0  29.8G  0 disk
├─sda1          8:1    0     1M  0 part
├─sda2          8:2    0   500M  0 part
│ └─md127       9:127  0   499M  0 raid1
│   └─md127p1 259:2    0   494M  0 part
├─sda3          8:3    0     2G  0 part
│ └─md125       9:125  0     2G  0 raid1
│   └─md125p1 259:1    0     2G  0 part
└─sda4          8:4    0    25G  0 part
  └─md126       9:126  0    25G  0 raid1
    └─md126p1 259:0    0    25G  0 part  /
sdb             8:16   0  29.8G  0 disk
├─sdb1          8:17   0     1M  0 part
├─sdb2          8:18   0   500M  0 part
│ └─md127       9:127  0   499M  0 raid1
│   └─md127p1 259:2    0   494M  0 part
├─sdb3          8:19   0     2G  0 part
│ └─md125       9:125  0     2G  0 raid1
│   └─md125p1 259:1    0     2G  0 part
└─sdb4          8:20   0    25G  0 part
  └─md126       9:126  0    25G  0 raid1
    └─md126p1 259:0    0    25G  0 part  /
sdc             8:32   0   118G  0 disk
└─sdc1          8:33   0   118G  0 part
sdd             8:48   0  29.5G  0 disk
├─sdd1          8:49   0     1M  0 part
├─sdd2          8:50   0   500M  0 part
│ └─md127       9:127  0   499M  0 raid1
│   └─md127p1 259:2    0   494M  0 part
├─sdd3          8:51   0     2G  0 part
│ └─md125       9:125  0     2G  0 raid1
│   └─md125p1 259:1    0     2G  0 part
└─sdd4          8:52   0    25G  0 part
  └─md126       9:126  0    25G  0 raid1
    └─md126p1 259:0    0    25G  0 part  /


Did you check how it works under 24.04 LTS or 22.04 LTS? I would recommend sticking to an LTS release.

Yes, it was working fine on 22.04. Was on LTS since 16, tried normal once and now must pay.

Try upgrading to 24.04. If that does not work, fresh install 22.04 (it will have extended support until 2032), so you really don't have to upgrade the server in the meanwhile

There is something definitely wrong with driver support on 23.10 and 24.04 as live server CDs have the same issue of not detecting my multibay storage "appendage". Went back to a clean install of 22.04 LTS, which recognized everything right away. I wonder how long do I have to stay on 22.04 until driver support is brought back into a more recent LTS.
